# How to make the Bing Map Autosuggest popup to be same width as the associated textbox?

Tags: css, bing-maps

In this [sample](http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/Autosuggest/Fill%20Address%20Form%20with%20Autosuggest.html), as you start typing into the textbox, a list of auto suggestions appears.  I would like the width of this AutoSuggest popup to be as wide as the textbox.

But it seems that the AutoSuggest popup is set to be a certain width with no way to override it. I've tried setting the width css attribute, but it looks like the object is destroyed and rebuilt every time it pops up (or so it seems to me).

Is there a way to override the width of the AutoSuggest popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste it in your CSS and set the width as per your requirement

```
div#as_container {
    max-width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really work, but you gave me an idea.  `.typeahead.dropdown-menu { width: 700px; }`  That did work.

Answer (score 1):

as a last resort you can listen onChange and 'correct' the width after each key press.